# why there is "---" in the beginning of the localisation files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

in some project I am investigating, for some localisation files in english, I found there is "---" in the beginning of the file. I would like the purpose of the "---".

Comment: Perhaps it would make sense to post a sample using "---".

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21251309/removing-on-top-of-yaml-file which points you to the YAML spec and explains `---`.

Comment: We probably should have also noted that localization files can be written in YAML or plain old ruby hashes as discussed in the guides here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/i18n.html#configure-the-i18n-module

Answer (score 1):

From YAML [specs](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html) - 2.2 Structures:

> YAML uses three dashes (“---”) to separate directives from document content. This also serves to signal the start of a document if no directives are present.