# How to convert symbols to strings (i.e. strip leading :) ruby to_yaml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, yaml

Am trying to remove the leading `:` from my YAML output. Here is the code and what I have done below:

**model/attribution_channel.rb**

```
DEFAULT_BONUS_CONFIG =  {
  sign_up: {
    currency: 'ngn',
    type: 'flat',
    amount: 1000
  },
  visit: {
    currency: 'ngn',
    type: 'flat',
    amount: 5
  }
}
```

**view/form.slim.html**

```
AttributionChannel::DEFAULT_BONUS_CONFIG.to_yaml
```

**The Output:**

[image: Output]

To remove the **YAML Separator ---** and the **Leading : in the keys** from my output, here is what I have done:

```
AttributionChannel::DEFAULT_BONUS_CONFIG.to_yaml.gsub("---\n", '').sub(":", '')
```

..but the `.sub(":", '')` part removed only the `:` of the first leading `:`.

How do I remove the leading `:` from my YAML output? Any help is appreciated? Here is what I want below:

```
sign_up:
  currency: ngn
  type: flat
  amount: 1000
visit:
  currency: ngn
  type: flat
  amount: 5
```

Comment: just call .to_s

Comment: @wasipeer calling `.to_s` on this YAML wont work surly

Comment: use .gsub(":", '') instad of .sub(":", '')

Comment: If you don't want the keys to be symbols why do you make them symbols in the first case?

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag Thank you so much. This is what am thinking at the moment. But making it symbol just looks cleaner to my face, is why I didn't make the constant a string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to have keys as strings to skip `:` generation

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/hash/keys'
require 'yaml'

DEFAULT_BONUS_CONFIG.deep_stringify_keys.to_yaml.gsub("---\n", '')

 => "sign_up:\n  currency: ngn\n  type: flat\n  amount: 1000\nvisit:\n  currency: ngn\n  type: flat\n  amount: 5\n"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can convert hash keys to strings before generating YAML. The code below goes through a hash recursively convering every key to hash and stringifying every value if it's a hash (note that it's not prepared for circular dependencies in hash).

```
def stringify(hash)
  hash.map{|k, v| [k.to_s, v.is_a?(Hash) ? stringify(v) : v] }.to_h
end  

puts stringify(DEFAULT_BONUS_CONFIG).to_yaml

---
sign_up:
  currency: ngn
  type: flat
  amount: 1000
visit:
  currency: ngn
  type: flat
  amount: 5
```

EDIT: Regarding the `---` at the beginning, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21251413/580346).